# Reading from istream

Tags: c++, istream

How can I extract data (contents) from istream without using operator>>() ?.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I'm with Jan on that, the way to extract data from `std::istream` is `operator>>()`. Tell us what you want to do (and probably why) and we might be able to answer your question.

Comment: @Jan I have private fnc which takes char*/string& as an argument and I would like to avoid creating tmp object just to pass it to this fnc.

Comment: me knowing you typical std::string implementations are reference-counted, so string copies are cheap. Even when your compiler uses a STL implementation with deep string copies this optimization should only be done when a profiler says that this copies are a bottleneck.

Comment: @Rudi: I'd expect a halfway decent `std::string` implementation to not to employ reference-counting (which MT'ing often turns into a pessimization), but the small string optimization.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to read characters from the istream, then by using get and getline:

[`std::istream::get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get)

[`std::istream::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline)

For general reading you may want to use read:

[`std::istream::read`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read)